# Synchronize identical files' timestamps across directory trees?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

In January of 2015, I transferred some files from a dd created backup image to a new hard disk. This transfer did not preserve timestamps, so basically every file shows a timestamp of January 20th.

Since then, many files have been modified, new files have been created, etc., but many more of the files are still identical (except for timestamp) to the copies on the dd image.

I would like to recursively copy the timestamps from the dd image's files to the matching files on the new disk, but only if the files are identical (i.e. only if the files have not been modified since the original copy).

I've tried various things with rsync, touch, etc., but I haven't been able to figure it out. I'm thinking that something like the following psuedocode would work, but I'm very unfamiliar with bash scripting.

```
for each file_in_dd_image
if (md5sum(file_in_dd_image) == md5sum(file_on_harddisk))
touch file_on_harddisk --reference=file_in_dd_image
```

Or, perhaps even better since it would also work if the file has been moved since being transferred, is there some way to process the output of `jdupes -rO dd_image harddisk`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use the tool `unison` with the `times` switch. It will synchronize file timestamps. However, it will not set directory timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar need, so here is my solution.

Bash scripts can be a bit tricky, especially when it comes to filenames with spaces, and if you do the wrong thing you could end up causing havoc, so it is best to split things up into manageable, testable pieces.

Part 1, a script that does the required behaviour for just one file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: copy_timestamp_if_identical.sh source_file dest_file

test "$#" -eq 2 || { echo "Wrong number of arguments" >&2; exit 1; }

FILE1="$1"
FILE2="$2"

test -f "$FILE1" || { echo "File \"$FILE1\" not found"  >&2; exit 1; }
test -f "$FILE2" || { echo "File \"$FILE2\" not found"  >&2; exit 1; }

if test "$(basename "$FILE1")" != "$(basename "$FILE2")";
then
    # Not same filename
    exit;
fi

if test $(md5sum "$FILE1" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) != $(md5sum "$FILE2" | cut -d ' ' -f 1);
then
    # Not same contents
    exit;
fi

echo "Updating \"$FILE2\" from \"$FILE1\""
touch -r "$FILE1" "$FILE2"
```

Part 2:

Use 'find' to do the recursive finding of files, which can be the tricky part.

This also allows more advanced conditions, including specifying the modification date, so you can avoid touching things that definitely shouldn't be touched, for safety and speed. See `-mtime` in `man find`.

For example, to find all files with a last modified timestamp of 1 year ago or more:

```
find "DEST_DIRECTORY" -type f -mtime +365
```

where DEST_DIRECTORY is the directory you want to fix. Check this returns the files you want to fix.

Part 3:

Combine the above two parts. This is slightly tricky, because of the need to pass two different files to `copy_timestamp_if_identical.sh`, which isn't easy with `find` and `-exec`. In the end I decided to write a helper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: copy_timestamp_if_identical_helper.sh file_in_dest_dir source_dir dest_dir

test "$#" -eq 3 || { echo "Wrong number of arguments" >&2; exit 1; }

DEST_FILE="$1"
SRC_DIR="$2"
DEST_DIR="$3"

SRC_FILE="$SRC_DIR${DEST_FILE:${#DEST_DIR}}"

echo copy_timestamp_if_identical.sh "$SRC_FILE" "$DEST_FILE"
```

You have to pass the source and dest dirs to it, as well as the file to modify, so the combined solution looks like:

```
find "DEST_DIR" -type f -mtime +365 -exec copy_timestamp_if_identical_helper.sh '{}' "SOURCE_DIR" "DEST_DIR" ';'
```